# Looking for a software that can block all applications except one from using the internet?

Tags: windows, internet, gaming

I want Windows software that blocks everything except one application of your choice. I want this for gaming. Oftentimes when gaming, there's like 5 or more other applications randomly using the internet without my concern, I believe I already disabled every update option on my apps... I noticed this is bad for my ping. I don't want to do this one by one via firewall.

Comment: Any firewall is specifically designed to do what you want. Simply block everything but the game and you're done.

Comment: blocking everything might cost you even more performance (context-switches, file-IO, e.g. just by logging events) than letting the background processes do their work. Besides, "privileged apps" that need network access such as Windows Defender, or backup-demons cannot really be prevented do something on the network.

Comment: I don't use Win enough to know - but can't you just set the firewall to reject all outgoing, except *xyz*? I'm used to [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) on Mac, which can easily do this & save it as a 'profile' so you can quickly switch between them.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, the best software that can do this that I've found (by accident) is NetBalancer. So very easy to set up...

Comment: Hmmm... NetBalancer doesn't seem to meet your requirements.  It's not gratis.  Or do they have a gratis version I'm not quickly seeing on their website?

Comment: I never mentioned "gratis" was the requirement, though it's definitely preferable. Besides, NetBalancer is totally worth it, underrated software that not many people know about it..

Comment: We use the `gratis` tag to indicate the software must be gratis (free of cost).  I'll remove the tag from the question, since it does not apply.  I'll also remove the `game` tag, as we use that tag for actual games.

Answer (score 0):

As fa as I know [QubesOS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) is the only one that can allows you to do so

Comment: You can easily do this on Mac using [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) [not free] No idea what equivalent there may be for Windows.